# Hmisc tilde rowname

Tags: r, hmisc

I am trying to group row names in a R data frame for typesetting with the Hmisc `latex()` function. Problem is that `latex()` adds two tilde characters before each row name, and these show up in my document.

How can I either remove these characters or have them not show up?

Example:

```
test.df <- data.frame(row.names=letters[1:4],   col1=1:4, col2=4:1, col3=4:7)
latex(test.df, file="", n.rgroup=c(2,2), rgroup=c("First","Second"))
```

Edit: 
The latex function occurs inside a knitr chunk. The resulting .Rnw file is compiled through the knit2pdf function, which uses pdfLatex by default, I think. All other tables/figures in the document compile fine, without any residual LaTex syntax showing up.

Answer (score 2):

They will not show up if you use `latex` with a TeX processor:

```
test.df <- data.frame(row.names=letters[1:4],   col1=1:4, col2=4:1, col3=4:7)
latex(test.df, file="test", n.rgroup=c(2,2), rgroup=c("First","Second"))
```

[image]

If you want to "capture" the text that is "printed" to the screen and remove the double tildes with `sub` then you probably need to use `capture.output`, because it appears that `latex` is not returning a value but is acting more like the `cat` function which has output to the screen as a side-effect:

```
out <- sub("^~~", "", capture.output( 
                     latex(test.df, file="", 
                         n.rgroup=c(2,2), rgroup=c("First","Second"))))
```

You could then use writeLines or cat with a file argument to send that text to a destination. I suppose it is possible that you could just put the `sub` call inline without diverting the results to a named object. That will depend on exactly how your are processing this text.

Comment: The latex function occurs inside a knitr chunk and the resulting .Rnw file is compiled with the knitr knit2pdf function. All other tables/figures in the document compile fine, so I think it is a problem specific to the tildes. (Original question edited with this information). Everything is going through a Tex processor. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The capture.output and sub solution worked perfectly. Thank you. The only remaining question would be: how to indent content in an Hmisc column without using tildes?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use LaTeX then i suggest either the [ascii package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ascii/ascii.pdf) that has pretty advanced options that do a nice raw text output (it also has the rgroup & n.rgroup options for grouping row names). If you are interested in getting the tables into a Word document (or just HTML) i suggest Markdown with my [htmlTable function](http://gforge.se/2013/02/tables-from-r-into-word/) - the arguments are based upon the Hmisc latex arguments as I needed a replacement when I was switching to Markdown, thus all you need to do is change the function name to htmlTable after loading my package.

Comment: This project is very much LaTex dependent at this point, but I will check out the ascii package in the future. Thank you for the tip.